# PreparedStatement Largest Query with Parameter Not Executing in Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to execute a Biggest SQL and with 6 date parameters and display in `JTable` but it not Executing, i Don't Know what is the actual problem.

But the confusing thing is i am able to execute the same query with fixed parameters using `Statement` interface and display in the JTable, but unable to Display using `PreparedStatement`

My Source Code:

```
public String start_date;
    public String end_date;

    public void getMonthWithDropCombobox()
    {
        if(month_sands.getSelectedIndex() != -1){
            int monthnumber = month_sands.getSelectedIndex() + 1;

             if(monthnumber>=9)
             {
                 month=String.valueOf(monthnumber);

             }else
             {
                 month="0"+String.valueOf(monthnumber);
             }

        }

        String dateString = year_sands.getSelectedItem().toString()+"-"+month+"-"+"01";   
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US); 
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormat);
        LocalDate startDate=date.withDayOfMonth(1);
        LocalDate endDate = date.withDayOfMonth(date.getMonth().maxLength());

        start_date=startDate.toString();
        end_date=endDate.toString();


    }

    public void getAllVendorDetails()
    {
        getMonthWithDropCombobox();

        StockAndSales sas1=new StockAndSales();
        if(company_dropdown_sas.getSelectedItem().equals("View All Vendors"))
        {

            try {


                String totalStockAndSales="select '' as Vendor_Company, '', product, price,sellprice, openingstock as openingStock, "
                + "openingstock*price as op_value, receipts as receipts, receipts*price as re_value, totalstock as totalstock, "
                + "totalstock*price as ts_value, sales as sales, sales*sellprice as s_value, return as returns,return*sellprice "
                + "as rt_value, closingstock as closingstock, closingstock*price as cl_value from purchase_table where date "

                + "between ? and ? "

                + "union all select orgname , 'TOTAL', '', sum(price),sum(sellprice), sum(openingstock) as openingStock, "
                + "sum(openingstock*price) as op_value, sum(receipts) as receipts, sum(receipts*price) as re_value, sum(totalstock) "
                + "as totalstock, sum(totalstock*price) as ts_value, sum(sales) as sales, sum(sales*sellprice) as s_value, sum(return) "
                + "as returns,sum(return*sellprice) as rt_value, sum(closingstock) as closingstock, sum(closingstock*price) as cl_value "
                + "from purchase_table where date "

                + "between ? and ? "

                + "group by orgname union all select 'Grand Total' , '', '',sum(price),sum(sellprice), sum(openingstock) as "
                + "openingStock, sum(openingstock*price) as op_value, sum(receipts) as receipts, sum(receipts*price) as re_value, "
                + "sum(totalstock) as totalstock, sum(totalstock*price) as ts_value, sum(sales) as sales, sum(sales*sellprice) as "
                + "s_value, sum(return) as returns,sum(return*sellprice) as rt_value, sum(closingstock) as closingstock, "
                + "sum(closingstock*price) as cl_value from purchase_table where date "

                + "between ? and ? "

                + "orde0r by closingstock asc";



            PreparedStatement ps_tsas=connection.prepareStatement(totalStockAndSales);
            ps_tsas.setString(1, start_date);
            ps_tsas.setString(2, end_date);
            ps_tsas.setString(3, start_date);
            ps_tsas.setString(4, end_date);
            ps_tsas.setString(5,start_date);
            ps_tsas.setString(6, end_date);

            ResultSet set_tsas=ps_tsas.executeQuery();
            sas1.table_sas.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(set_tsas));
            sas1.show_month_year_sas.setText("All Vendors Stock and Sales");
            sas1.name_of_user.setText(user_name_display.getText());
            sas1.setVisible(true);
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't just swallow exceptions (// TODO: handle exception). At least print out the exception message + stacktrace. With the exception message it would also be a lot easier to help (assuming an exception gets thrown)

Comment: Chances are that the string representation of your dates in the query, don't match the expected format on DB side. Try using the `setDate(int parameterIndex, java.sql.Date)` method of `PreparedStatement` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `setString()` there are `setDate()` for dates:

```
ps_tsas.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(start_date));
```

Example with real date :

```
ps_tsas.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2017-05-22"));
```

The same for the other dates.

Comment: I Don't Know how to thank you but, i am really Delighted you helped me, that worked +1 from me, But i am little confused here, in my all previous Prepared Statement's i used setString for all date parameter it worked, but why it did not work for this particular Query. any reasonable answer for that